# How to implement paypal in facebook application canvas using PHP?

Tags: php, facebook, payment-gateway, paypal

I want the user to subscribe my app in two ways means there are two choices say 200$ and 350$ subscription are available. Firstly I want to direct them to Paypal inside the canvas and then return to the app's page.I want to use PHP libraries ..

Answer (score 0):

Could you just implement *PayPal* as you would any other PHP application, and then specify the `return_url` parameter when your form's posted to *PayPal* as your Facebook app's URL?

Comment: that's the easiest approach. However I to handle cancel and success scenarios as they are separate files?

Comment: You would normally have a request handler in your index file that handles the incoming request's URL, and pass it off to whatever script you wanted then.

Comment: Was reading the terms and conditions, one has to use **Credits** for payment processing.

Comment: Well surely *PayPal* is a moot point then? You're probably best checking out http://developers.facebook.com/docs/credits/

Comment: They say "Per the Facebook Credits Terms, all games on the Facebook Platform ... must exclusively ...". I wonder about other apps. Anyone?

Comment: I don't think it's worth risking your app being shut down and annoying paying customers just because you took a gamble with Facebook, the multi-million dollar site, because their Ts and Cs didn't explicitly cover your app.